# SimpleMessageListenerContainer and IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring-amqp

I am getting "IllegalArgumentException" errors trying to do the following:

- Receive an AMQP message that forces me to stop a "SimpleMessageListenerContainer".
- Make an AMQP request using the "direct reply-to" mechanism.
- Restart the "SimpleMessageListenerContainer"

I have a Project with a SimpleMessageListenerContainer, listening in a queue called “USER-broadcast-queue”:

```
@Bean("broadcastMessageListenerContainer")
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer broadcastMessageListenerContainer() {
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(simpleRoutingConnectionFactory());
    container.setQueues(marketDataBroadcastQueue());
    container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter());
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    container.setDeclarationRetries(12);                    
    container.setFailedDeclarationRetryInterval(5000);
    container.setMismatchedQueuesFatal(true);
    container.setPrefetchCount(50);
    container.setAutoStartup(false);

    clientHandler.setBroadcastMessageListenerContainer(container);

    return container;
}

@Bean 
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() 
{
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(simpleRoutingConnectionFactory());
    template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    template.setUseDirectReplyToContainer(true);

    template.setRoutingKey(REQUEST_EXCHANGE_NAME);      
   template.setMandatory(true);
    template.setReplyTimeout(20000);    
    return template;
}
```

My ClientHandler is a vean defined like this:

```
@Component
public class ClientHandler{
        public void handleMessage(…) {….}
}



@Bean 
    public MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(clientHandler, jsonMessageConverter());       
    }
```

Now, when recibe some kind of message, I need to stop the container:

```
broadcastMessageListenerContainer.stop();
```

Ask a request to the server from a RabbitGatewaySupport (using direct reply-to):

```
_response = getRabbitOperations().convertSendAndReceive(requestExchange, routingKeyInquiry, myObject, 
new MessagePostProcessor() {
public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
…
return message;
            }
        });
```

And then start the listener again:

```
broadcastMessageListenerContainer.initialize();
broadcastMessageListenerContainer.start();
```

This is working fine the first time, but when I recibe a second message, I get this error when I try to send the request (convertSendAndReceive):

```
12-09-2019 13:54:13.826|DEBUG|USER|org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer|1233|[]|broadcastMessageListenerContainer-1|Shutting down Rabbit listener container
12-09-2019 13:54:13.826|TRACE| USER |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory|1063|[]|broadcastMessageListenerContainer-1|AMQChannel(amqp:// USER @127.0.0.1:5671/,3) channel.isOpen()
12-09-2019 13:54:13.826|TRACE| USER |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory|1063|[]|broadcastMessageListenerContainer-1|AMQChannel(amqp:// USER @127.0.0.1:5671/,3) channel.basicCancel([amq.ctag-6ztkTlFxReqUvLDJOsmmdQ])
12-09-2019 13:54:13.828|INFO | USER |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer|586|[]|broadcastMessageListenerContainer-1|Waiting for workers to finish.
12-09-2019 13:54:13.828|DEBUG| USER |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer|886|[]|pool-7-thread-9|Received cancelOk for tag amq.ctag-6ztkTlFxReqUvLDJOsmmdQ (USER -broadcast-queue); Consumer@5c20aab9: tags=[[amq.ctag-6ztkTlFxReqUvLDJOsmmdQ]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://USER@127.0.0.1:5671/,3), conn: Proxy@46baf579 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@48b0e701 [delegate=amqp:// USER @127.0.0.1:5671/, localPort= 55757], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
12-09-2019 13:54:18.829|INFO | USER |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer|592|[]|broadcastMessageListenerContainer-1|Workers not finished.
12-09-2019 13:54:18.829|WARN | USER |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer|596|[]|broadcastMessageListenerContainer-1|Closing channel for unresponsive consumer: Consumer@5c20aab9: tags=[[amq.ctag-6ztkTlFxReqUvLDJOsmmdQ]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp:// USER@127.0.0.1:5671/,3), conn: Proxy@46baf579 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@48b0e701 [delegate=amqp:// USER @127.0.0.1:5671/, localPort= 55757], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
12-09-2019 13:54:18.829|DEBUG| USER |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer|735|[]|broadcastMessageListenerContainer-1|Closing Rabbit Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp:// USER @127.0.0.1:5671/,3), conn: Proxy@46baf579 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@48b0e701 [delegate=amqp:// USER@127.0.0.1:5671/, localPort= 55757]
12-09-2019 13:54:18.829|TRACE| USER |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory|1063|[]|broadcastMessageListenerContainer-1|AMQChannel(amqp:// USER @127.0.0.1:5671/,3) channel.close()
12-09-2019 13:54:18.830|DEBUG| USER |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory|1276|[]|broadcastMessageListenerContainer-1|Closing cached Channel: AMQChannel(amqp:// USER @127.0.0.1:5671/,3)

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Already value [[USER-broadcast-queue]] for key [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory@a50b09c] bound to thread [broadcastMessageListenerContainer-1]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:176) ~[MyLib-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleResourceHolder.bind(SimpleResourceHolder.java:125) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.doConsumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:659) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.adjustConsumers(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:313) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.setConsumersPerQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:161) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer.getChannelHolder(DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer.java:190) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSendAndReceiveWithDirect(RabbitTemplate.java:1896) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSendAndReceive(RabbitTemplate.java:1762) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveRaw(RabbitTemplate.java:1731) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(RabbitTemplate.java:1600) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(RabbitTemplate.java:1591) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at es.siom.trading.amqp.gateway.RabbitServiceGateway.sendAndReceiveInquiry(RabbitServiceGateway.java:123) ~[Salida/:?]
    at es.siom.trading.amqp.ui.UIController.sendAndReceiveInquiry(UIController.java:67) ~[Salida/:?]
    at es.siom.trading.utils.ModuloTradingUtils.consultaContratosMercadoPublic(ModuloTradingUtils.java:627) ~[Salida/:?]
    at es.siom.trading.utils.ModuloTradingUtils.leeMercado(ModuloTradingUtils.java:133) ~[Salida/:?]
    at es.siom.trading.amqp.beans.DatosGeneralesLTS.actualizaOfertas(DatosGeneralesLTS.java:602) ~[Salida/:?]
    at es.siom.trading.amqp.handler.ClientHandler.handleMessage(ClientHandler.java:89) ~[Salida/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:280) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:363) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:292) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1552) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1478) ~[ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1466) [ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461) [ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1410) [ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870) [ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854) [ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78) [ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137) [ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043) [ClasesAuxCliente-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]
```

Any ideas, any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug.

It's an artifact of the fact that the reply-to container is initialized lazily; we shouldn't be binding its connection factory to the calling thread.

Please open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues).

As a work around, you can delegate the send to another thread.

By the way, stopping the container on the listener thread will pause for the `shutDownTimeout` before actually stopping the active consumer(s).

**EDIT**

[Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1091).

Comment: Sorry to ping here... but if you have any idea to put on :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912448/rabbithandler-to-create-consumer-and-retry-on-fatal-exception-in-spring-for-queu

Comment: It is unnecessary to do this; we monitor all questions tagged with [tag:spring-amqp] (and others).